Non-linear Eigenvalue problem with an ODE to solve for the Linear Stability Theory of a Boundary Layer
I am working on the Linear Stability Theory (LST) for analysing the stability of a boundary layer in fluid mechanics. I have conducted CFD simulations and extracted the base flow data. To form the LST here's a brief overview of the process followed:

Linearisation of the Navier-Stokes Equations: I linearised the Navier-Stokes equations and decomposed the variables into a base flow and a fluctuating component. The fluctuating component was further decomposed using normal mode approximation: $\exp[i(\alpha x + \beta z - \omega t)]$

Formulation of the ODE: This leads to a second-order ordinary differential equation (ODE): $\left(A \frac{d^2}{dy^2} + B \frac{d}{dy} + C\right) \hat{q} = 0$, where A, B and C are 5 by 5 matrices and $\hat{q}$ is a vector of the variable amplitudes: $[\hat{u}, \hat{v}, \hat{p}, \hat{T}, \hat{w}]^T$. The matrices B and C are functions of the wavenumbers $(\alpha, \beta, \omega)$ which are given by $ \lambda$. For spatial stability $ \omega$ is kept real and is an input and the wavenumbers are split into a real and imaginary. The simulation is 2D, so $ \beta =0$, and only $ \alpha$ needs to be found.

Boundary Conditions: The boundary conditions of the ODE are: $\hat{u}(0) = \hat{v}(0) = \hat{p}(0) - 1 = \hat{T}(0) = \hat{w}(0) = 0$ and $\lim_{y \to \infty} \hat{u}(y) = \hat{v}(y) = \hat{p}(y) = \hat{T}(y) = \hat{w}(y) = 0$


To evaluate the stability, an eigenvalue problem (EVP) is solved: $L\hat{q} = \lambda \hat{q}$, where $L$ is the operator: $\left(A \frac{d^2}{dy^2} + B \frac{d}{dy} + C\right)
$, $\lambda $ represents the eigenvalues and $\hat{q}$ represents the corresponding eigenvectors. The appendix of this paper gives the matrices B and C: https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19820020697/downloads/19820020697.pdf
My questions is:
How is the EVP solved, given there is an ODE involved, whose derivative is the eigenvector. The matrices B and C contain $\alpha$ as an imaginary component which squared, making it non-linear. Having the $\alpha$ in the matrices mean I will have to use an iterative method, what is a cost efficient method I could you to deal with the non-linearity?
The data from the simulation has ~2500 streamwise with 200 wall normal boundary layer evaluations, so its quite expensive.
Any advice or insights on these issues would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

The. partial differential terms are analyzed by representing each of the dependent variables by a function having the periodic form of the disturbance, each with different $\alpha$ and $\omega$ coefficients.

I am only looking at the spatial stability, meaning $ \omega$ will be a constant real value. $ \alpha$ is an unknown which I am solving for, given by $ \lambda$. However matrices B and C are functions of $ \alpha$, so I need to have an initial guess then iterate. This is one of the parts I am confused about.
